# Joomla Menu not displaying title

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template, joomla2.5

I was wondering if some people could help, I have this code in my template:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('quick_links_1')): ?>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="quick_links_1" />                        
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have also created a menu which I have assigned to that position in Joomla admin, and the menu is displaying fine.

In the menu configuration I have "Show title" set to "show" but, it is not displaying the menu heading.

Any ideas? Also whilst I am on the subject, I cannot find the component (like com_content) for menus on the front end, I would like to be able to override the default display for menus so I can some extra HTML. Could you point me in the right direction?

I am using Joomla 2.5.

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to fuigure it out in the end, it was the jdoc include:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="quick_links_1" />
```

Which needs to be like this:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="quick_links_1" style="xhtml" />
```

I ended up setting up my own modChrome in modules.php in the template folder. For more information on this, have a look here: http://docs.joomla.org/Applying_custom_module_chrome

And also as Javex says, there is no com_menu, it is in modules/mod_menu, I don't know why I didn't look in there!

Comment: How can you display the actual menu title but not the module menu title that is assigned to it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "com_menus" for the frontend. You will want to look at "mod_mainmenu" in folder "modules". Do a copy of that and rename your new one in the appropriate files.

In this process you could also check why it is not displaying your title by checking the source code. Maybe a modification (for whatever reason) has been made here.

Furthermore, if you provide me with a url I may be able to look into the problem (maybe it is a display issue?).